# Twillio channel's sorting by last message timestampe

Tags: android, twilio

I am using **Twilio SDK** to integrate chat functionality.

SDK : `com.twilio:chat-android:0.12.1`

I can fetch the channel list successfully. Now I need to sort the channel list by the last message timestamp in that channel.

Comment: What's the code you have so far? What have you tried for sorting the channel list?

Answer (score 0):

This SDK is **extremely** old and is unsupported. It makes sense to update to 2.0.5.

The current method to sort channels by message timestamp is as follows:

Please note that this is slow and incurs a lot of traffic overhead, so it's only useful on first message start, afterwards it's much cheaper to track last message timestamps per channel locally.

(in pseudocode)

```
client.getChannels().each(channel =>
   channel.getLastMessages(1).each(message =>
       use message.getTimeStampAsDate() as the sorting timestamp
   )
)
```